# Hide DataGridView default Row Selection

Tags: c#, datagridview, colors

Here i am using some color codes to Highlight rows with a refresh button but DataGridView selection always set to 1st row after every refresh and default selected color(Blue) will override my 1st row color always.

I need to hide that default color in row 1 after refreshing and then user select the grid view 
to select a row, so at this time row selection is doesn't matter for me...

Here is my code...I hope this make sense of my problem...

```
private void btnRefreshCutDGV_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tablePlanMainBL.ColorMainGrid(dgvMainCut);
}

public void ColorMainGrid(DataGridView dgvCol)
{
    dgvCol.Refresh();

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvCol.Rows)     
    {
        if (int.Parse(row.Cells[7].Value.ToString()) == 2)
        {
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.OrangeRed;
        }
        else if (int.Parse(row.Cells[7].Value.ToString()) == 3)
        {
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.SpringGreen;
        }            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After refreshing set

```
dgvCol.CurrentCell = null;
```